# PHP references difference between two examples?

Tags: php, reference

What is the difference in php if I do either

```
$temp = &$files;
```

Or

```
$temp =& $files;
```

I do not understand

Thanks

Comment: The first example I have never seen, and seen it on someone elses code and did not understand it. Hence the question

Comment: As with most programming languages (not Python though), spaces are completely ignored.

Comment: i didn't want to be rude, I'm sorry, but this is a really awkward question

Comment: @Sebas I am sure as you are probably a well educated programmer that these kind of questions bug you. But as I did not know they are the same and could not find the first example anywhere about references in the php docs the only thing I could do was ask. :)

Comment: I'd say this is a very valid question. PHP docs are vague enough regarding the `&` operator, and while "assignment by reference" examples always uses the `$var1 =& $var2` style, there is no `=&` operator in the docs, only a `&` operator.

Comment: lanzz, a simple test case would reveal that they are equal, though. I can understand downvotes for this question based on that.

Comment: In my humble opinion (and i apologize again I didn't mean to be rude) I think this is more about having programming principle. You can't pretend to be structured the way you program if you don't mind having such kind of weird syntax in your code.

Comment: @Sebas: Which syntax is weird in your opinion?

Comment: if the idea is to pass a reference to a variable, the admitted syntax is the first one.

Comment: @Sebas: The PHP documentation disagrees with you, and consistently uses the second syntax. I, personally, am _with_ you on this one: the first syntax is more consistent with the two other reference operations (pass by reference and return by reference). Still, the style you and I prefer is clearly **not** the "canonical" style endorsed by the PHP team, thus you can hardly call the official style "weird".

Comment: This is a matter of background as well. I *think* (but I can't sware) that `=&` is common for C-programmers. Normally you can use both variants as PHP coders are used to both. You might want to do the same as the PHP docs do, but you *might* want to check coding styleguides like PEAR or Zend first to get a broader view if you like.

Comment: When you pass a reference parameter to a function it is noted with &varname ... Ok for the C background, this is a huge argument.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no difference. It is a matter of code style preference.

Answer (score 1):

The difference is where you put whitespace.

You can use whitespace vertically to create awareness of something. Take a look:

```
$temp =& $files;

$temp = &$files;

$temp = & $files;

$temp =  &  $files;

$temp=  &  $files;
```

And horizontal whitespace works as well:

```
$temp= 
& $files;
```

Somewhere then it stops to make sense to do any more variations.

Keep the `&` close to either the `=` or the `$` so that it's clear it's to alias a variable and not the same looking [`&` operator](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.bitwise.php):

```
$alias = &$variable;

$alias =& $variable;
```